# VBA use filter to exclude item in string array

Tags: vba, excel

First of all, excuse me if the code below does not contain an array but a list. I am new to VBA so I don't know all the basics yet. The code below retrieves an array (or a list) of all Excel files in a certain folder. The code is used to retrieve data from each file and is pasted in a master file.
Okay, here is my MWE:

```
    Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String, wbCount As Integer
    FolderName = "C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\Test"
        wbCount = 0
        wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xlsm")
        While wbName <> ""
            wbCount = wbCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
            wbList(wbCount) = wbName
            wbName = Dir
        Wend
        If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

Now here is the problem: The array contains a template file, and the name of the file contains the word *TEMPLATE*. How do I filter out (or exclude) the file which file name contains the string "TEMPLATE"?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `wbName` contains the filenames from the `Dir` command. Check to see if the string contains what you want to exlude.

Extend the line

```
While wbName <> ""
```

into

```
While wbName <> "" And InStr(1, UCase(wbName), "TEMPLATE") = 0
```

to exlude any filenames that contain `TEMPLATE`, regardless of case.

**EDIT**

The logic in my suggestion above was wrong, it stopped when it encountered the first filename containing "TEMPLATE". Try the following instead:

```
    While wbName <> ""
        '***** Only add to wbCount if wbName does not contain TEMPLATE
        If InStr(1, UCase(wbName), "TEMPLATE") = 0 Then
            wbCount = wbCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
            wbList(wbCount) = wbName
        End If
        wbName = Dir
    Wend
```

**EDIT 2**

Some general tips on finding errors:

- Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. It will force you to declare your variables, minimizing the risk of typos etc introducing bugs.
- Step through your code using <kbd>F8</kbd> to identify errors and checking vaules of variables and functions
- If possible, remove code to simplify it, only keeping the logic like `While` loops and `If` statements to make sure the basics work. Then add the details back.

Finally, the key to my solution is finding the files that contain "TEMPLATE" in the name. The statement `InStr(1, UCase(wbName), "TEMPLATE") = 0` will be `False` for all files containing the string "TEMPLATE" anywhere, regardless of case, and `True` otherwise. (The `Ucase` part is what makes the statement case insensitive.)

Try to add it to your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I extend the line, the macro does not seem to do anything anymore. I checked the result of
        InStr(1, UCase(wbName), "TEMPLATE") = 0
with a messagebox, but it didn't show anything.

Comment: Ah, it does seem to work when it is used in a messagebox. If used in the while statement, it does not work.

Comment: @RobinTrietsch Take the name of file in a separate variable x=split(wbName,"."). Then run the loop to UBound of "x" and check for UCase(x)= "TEMPLATE" . I think this should work.

Comment: @Brain Thanks for your reply. That does not seem to work either. Nevertheless, I need to find and exclude the file that contains the word "TEMPLATE".

Comment: Sorry, not enough testing with your code. Changed the logic to an `If` statement within the `While` loop instead.

Comment: @RobinTrietsch One thing more I Would like to know... will your file name may contains file name like this e.g. (1) Template XYz.xlsx , (2) Template_Xyz.xlsx?

Comment: @OlleSjögren Including an If statement didn't work either. It freezes when using an If statement inside the While loop.

Comment: Then you will have to step through the code to see where it hangs. I have run your code, but with the lines containing referecnes to `wbList` commented out, since I could not get them to compile. Your code with my changes works in my environment (Excel 2010).

Comment: Somehow, it didn't work the first time. Now it works! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: OK, great! Read the last edit about debugging anyway, it will probably help you if you have other VBA problems in the future. :)

Comment: Yeah, probably will need some more training in VBA. But debugging certainly is useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim fNameList As Variant
Dim storFName As String
Dim i As Integer
Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String, wbCount As Integer
FolderName = "C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\Test"
    wbCount = 0
    wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xlsm")
    While wbName <> ""
        wbCount = wbCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
        fNameList = Split(wbName, ".")
        For i = 0 To UBound(fNameList) '<- Here i is being use
            If (UCase(InStr(fNameList(i), "TEMPLATE"))) Then
               UCase(storFName) = fNameList (i)
            End If
        Next i '<- Here i is being increase
        If storFName <> "TEMPLATE" Then
            wbList(wbCount) = wbName
            wbName = Dir
        End If
    Wend
    If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Will it work for you?

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the file ending, since the question says to exlude files where the `name contains the string "TEMPLATE"`. The `InStr` function will take care of all those files.

Comment: Okay, That's what I want to know, will file name may be like this e.g. (1) Template XYz.xlsx , (2) Template_Xyz.xlsx?

Comment: I think so, but OP would have to say.

Comment: @Brain The template file name looks like: "SOMETEXT V2_1 TEMPLATE.xlsm"

Comment: @Brain Unfortunately, the macro still uses the TEMPLATE file with your solution.

Comment: @RobinTrietsch if the format of file name is "SOMETEXT V2_1 TEMPLATE.xlsm" then you can again split fNameList(1) usinf space i.e. "". Then again loop through it you will find String "TEMPLATE" there. I am updating my code.

Comment: @Brain Thanks for all your effort in helping me, much appreciated! Olle's solution worked eventually :)

Comment: @RobinTrietsch Look at my code if it works then make me know. I will be happy if it works I worked a lot for it :-)

Comment: @Brain Yes of course I'll check it for you! The code gives a Type Mismatch error. Maybe because you declare j as an integer, but it isn't used in a for loop or incremented in the for loop where i is used?

Comment: @RobinTrietsch Sorry It is j there, I have to change J to i. I am editing code. Now I think it should work.

Comment: @Brain Still gives a Type Mismatch on: UCase(storFName) = fNameSecPart(i)

Comment: I am extreamly sorry fNameSecPart(i) is not being use I changed it to fNameList(i). Please check it now.

Comment: No problem. Next error: UCase(storFName) = fNameList(i) "Object Required"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim x() As String, i As Integer
    x = ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder("C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\Test")
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        Debug.Print x(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder(FolderName As String) As Variant
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim wbCount As Integer
    Dim wbList() As String
    wbCount = 0
    ReDim wbList(0)
    wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\*.xlsm")
    While wbName <> vbNullString
        If Not (UCase(wbName) Like "*TEMPLATE*") Then
            ReDim Preserve wbList(wbCount)
            wbList(wbCount) = wbName
            wbCount = wbCount + 1
        End If
        wbName = Dir
    Wend
    ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder = wbList
End Function
```

Once you get comfortable with VBA you'll probably switch to Scripting.FileSystemObject and Scripting.Dictionary...

Comment: Thanks Apropos. I implemented the code, but like with the solution from Olle Sjögren, the macro does not do anything anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Apropos. Eventually, Olle's solution worked.